# How to separate by comma all the elements of a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have a long list with tokens like this:

```
 a_lis = [['hi how are you'],
['im fine thanks'],
['cool lets go to the restaurant']
,...,
['I can't now']]
```

I would like to separate each token or term with a comma like this (*):

```
 a_lis = [['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'],
['im', 'fine', 'thanks'],
['cool', 'lets', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'restaurant']
,...,
['I', 'can't', 'now']]
```

I tried to:

```
[x.replace(' ', ', ') for x in a_lis]
```

However, is not working. Amy idea of how to get (*)?

Comment: Those aren't valid python literals.  What exactly is `a_lis`?  A list containing lists that each contain a single string?

Comment: is a nested list with one string @PatrickHaugh

Comment: sorry @PatrickHaugh I fixed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a_lis` is

```
a_lis = [["hi how are you"],
["im fine thanks"],
["cool lets go to the restaurant"],
["I can't now"]]
```

then we can flatten that to a list of strings, and `split` each of those strings

```
[s.split() for l in a_lis for s in l]
```

gives us

```
[['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['im', 'fine', 'thanks'], ['cool', 'lets', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'restaurant'], ['I', "can't", 'now']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I end up with some `''` spaces, is there any way of removing them?

Comment: Are you using `s.split()` or `s.split(' ')`?  `s.split()` shouldn't produce `''`.  What strings are leading to those outputs?

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it with map

```
a_lis = [["hi how are you"],["good and you"]]
new_list = list(map(lambda x: x[0].split(' '), a_lis))
# new_list is [['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['good', 'and', 'you']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a_list = ['hmm this is a thing', 'and another']
new_list = []
for i in a_list:
    new_list.append(i.split(' '))
print(new_list)
```

Basically, use the `.split()` method for a string with a space as an argument. Also, make sure you put quotation marks around those strings!

If you have a list of lists, just add another for loop:

```
a_list = [['hmm, this is a thing', 'and another'], ['more things!']]
new_list = []
for i in a_list:
    sub_list = []
    for k in i:
        sub_list.append(k.split(' '))
    new_list.append(sub_list)
```

Comment: I got the folowing: `----> 3     new_list.append(i.split(' '))
      4 print(new_list)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: @anon that's because you ran the first example, for a flat list - try the next example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional approach:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> a_lis = [["hi how are you"],["good and you"]]
>>> list(map(str.split, map(itemgetter(0), a_lis)))
[['hi', 'how', 'are', 'you'], ['good', 'and', 'you']]
```